# mempool.used_bytes and mempool.total_bytes discrepancy results in cupy.cuda.memory.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: python, cupy

I can run the code provided in the example https://docs-cupy.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/memory.html and the result of

`mempool.used_bytes = mempool.total_bytes`

However when I try my own code, It always results in

`mempool.total_bytes > mempool.used_bytes`

and i don´t know where is all that memory going. I'm also using "del" and cp._default_memory_pool.free_all_blocks() after every iteration.

My code creates 2 matrixes NxN x_1 and x_2 and loops N

`x_1 = cp.ones((N,N))+1
 x_2 = cp.ones((N,N))+1`

then asigns the value of a third matrix

`y_gpu = np.multiply( np.power(x_gpu,2), np.power(x_gpu,2) )`

So in total, the memory required is 3 * 8(bytes per number) * (N)^2

mempool.used_bytes give me this number however mempool.total_bytes > mempool.used_bytes.

for example, with N = 5000, `mempool.used_bytes = 600 M` but `mempool.total_bytes = 1200 M` 
with  N = 6000 mempool.used_bytes would be 864 M but the cupy.cuda.memory.OutOfMemoryError kicks in

Can someone please give me some insight with what is happening here ? 
thanks !

```
    import cupy as cp
    import numpy as np
    from timeit import default_timer as timer
    import time 

    def GPU(N):
        t_gpu_1 = time.time()
        x_1 = cp.ones((N,N))+1
        x_2 = cp.ones((N,N))+1
        t_gpu_2 = time.time()
        y_gpu = cp.zeros((N,N))
        y_gpu = cp.multiply( cp.power(x_1,2), cp.power(x_2,2) )
        t_gpu_1 = time.time() - t_gpu_1
        t_gpu_2 = time.time() - t_gpu_2

        print("Alloc + Computo GPU ",t_gpu_1," Computo GPU ",t_gpu_2)
        print("matrixes size >> ",y_gpu.nbytes * 3/1e6)
        print("BEFORE DEL")
        print("used Mbytes >> ",mempool.used_bytes()/1e6)              # 
        print("total Mbytes >> ",mempool.total_bytes()/1e6)
        time.sleep(3)
        del x_1
        del x_2
        del y_gpu
        cp._default_memory_pool.free_all_blocks()
        print("AFTER DEL + FREE")
        print("used Mbytes >> ",mempool.used_bytes()/1e6)              # 
        print("total Mbytes >> ",mempool.total_bytes()/1e6)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        mempool = cp.get_default_memory_pool()
        print("Device >> ", cp.cuda.runtime.getDeviceCount())
        #print("Limit >> ",mempool.get_limit()) 

        for N in range(1,10,1):
            print("N >> ",N*1e3)
            #CPU(N*1e3)
            GPU(int(N*1e3))
            cp._default_memory_pool.free_all_blocks()
```